# Statement with if and then

Tags: logic

Write the following in the form of if a then b: [The weather is bad when there's clouds.]

a then b: If there's clouds then the weather is bad.[correct?]

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Except that should be "If (when) there *are* clouds."

Comment: It really *isn't* good form to keep posing trivial questions which suggest that you haven't bothered to consult some elementary textbooks before asking here ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When a statement is phrased as "$b$ when $a$", it can be directly translated to:

$$b\leftarrow{a}$$

Reverse the arrow and you get the more familiar:

$$a\to{b}$$